# Is it possible to get list of City between City A and City B in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to get list of cities between City A and City B in Google Maps. Is it possible ? because I cannot figure it out how to do it when I look at the Google Maps API

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858913/api-to-type-city-name-and-get-a-list-of-possible-cities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not. You would have to do some reverse geocoding of a bunch of lat/lngs in between the cities.

Comment: Thank you Galen for the respond, guess I have to try another solution. Do you know such service ? Or do you another solution maybe ?