# API to type city name and get a list of possible cities?

Tags: google-maps, maps

I need to know on which city my users are.

I cannot use a regular text input since there are similar named cities and users can call the same city by different names,.

I want to let users type their city and display a list of similar results, I could do it with a world cities database, jquery and sql but I'm really not dying to do it from a scratch.

Is there any api (e.g: google) that has an unique ID for each city in the world and let's you search them? Could you post a link to a similar implementation?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is the Google Places Autocomplete API,
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

and a library for Maps Version 3 at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

but I don't know how well it will cope with different names for the same city — although, having [tried it](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), it does present **Munich, Germany** for *munchen* — see how well your use case performs.

Comment: Thanks a lot I had no idea there was such API.