# Google Maps: how to get city list given a country code value?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

When I give the COUNTRY. I want to have a list (JSON or whatever) which contains all the cities for that country.

How can I achieve this with Google Maps or other service if not possible.

Thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858913/api-to-type-city-name-and-get-a-list-of-possible-cities

Answer (score 0):

You can try the gem 'cities' --> https://github.com/joecorcoran/cities

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).