# Java, get cities based on a chosen state

Tags: java, android, maps

I have two spinner boxes in an Android application.  The first spinner box is a string array of the different states in the United States.  I want the second spinner to populate with the cities within the selected state.

How can I go about getting a list of those cities?  Some API I can use?  Do I need a pre-defined CSV file that contains this data so I can import it into a SQLite DB?

**EDIT:**
As a follow on to this, here is how I continued forth to incorporate what I wanted to do.  I pushed the JSON from the endpoint into a string, then eventually to a JSONArray:

```
                    inStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    //sb.append("{\"cities\":");
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
                        //sb.append("}");
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
```

From there, I looped through the array and placed each "name" of city into an ArrayList:

```
    ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        int rootSize = jsonArray.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < rootSize; i++){
            JSONObject inner = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //String firstChildren = inner.getString("name");
            cities.add(inner.getString("name"));
            //double secondChildren = inner.getDouble(1);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Collections.sort(cities);

    return cities;
```

With the ArrayList in hand, I used the list adapter and bound it to my cities spinner.  Done!:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cities);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    spnrCity.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: What do you consider a city?  How small does a municipality need to be before you don't want to display it?  For large cities, do you want to display the greater metropolitan area as a single city, or do you want to list the suburbs/exurbs separately?

Comment: All that being said, the [google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858913/api-to-type-city-name-and-get-a-list-of-possible-cities) API will probably do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using SBA.gov API. Here is the link [SBA API STATE AND CITY](https://www.sba.gov/about-sba/sba-performance/sba-data-store/web-service-api/us-city-and-county-web-data-api#city-county-state)

Specifically this endpoint may be what you need to use     http://api.sba.gov/geodata/city_links_for_state_of/tx.json

Go ahead and click on the link above, you'll be able to see the data that is returned. It returns all cities within TX.

Comment: No problem, if you have any trouble parsing the JSON or making the call don't hesitate to ask on stackoverflow and tag me!

Comment: The SBA API reference page has changed and is now http://api.sba.gov/doc/geodata.html

The api call itself is still valid.

Comment: this link is also not working. Do we need any reliable place from where i can get state and town and their relationship.

Comment: Links are dead.