# How to get list of area names by city name from google api in PHP

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I want to get the list of all area names from the city name in google api. can anyone provide me the link to refer in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API to type city name and get a list of possible cities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858913/api-to-type-city-name-and-get-a-list-of-possible-cities)

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain i fallowed your link but its not giving proper result i tried to call this link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=delhi&types=(cities)&language=fr&key=sdag

Comment: Go get a key. Your key is invalid.

[link]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain just i changed the key in comment. can you try once with your key

Comment: you are sending "sdag" in key!!

Comment: No i am sending  with my api key.

Comment: post your key here! If possible.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain this is the link i was executing with my api key [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=delhi&types=(cities)&key=AIzaSyB8mcnpK6yM0zwhFTvMqsoIB4aHVO6e4Jg)
after executing it showing some other results.can you give me exact api  url